# Error with using Promise function in javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to use a Promise function. The promise function is nested inside the dataService function. And the dataService function has a getData method inside, it defines a promise and then checks , if the number inside generated randomly is greater than 5 then the promise variable executes resolve else its a reject (inbuilt promise parameters). The then property logs the answer. However i am getting errors like - 
  Cannot read property 'then' of undefined  and Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at Promise.html:19.
Please help.

```
 <html>

 <head>
<title>Promise</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
   function dataService() {
        var obj = {};
        console.log('inside function');

        obj.getData = function () {
            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

                var number = Math.random() * 10;

                if (number > 5) {
                   ( promise.resolve("Resolved promise " + number));

                }
                else
              ( promise.reject("Promise Rejected " + number));

        })};

            return obj;

        }


    var data = dataService();
    console.log(data);

   data.getData()
        .then(function(val) {
            console.log("It has been a success"),
            console.log(val)
         } )
        .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("It has been failed"),
                console.log(err)
        });
  </script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the Promise when the function is called:

```js
function dataService() {
        var obj = {};
        console.log('inside function');

        obj.getData = function () {
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

                var number = Math.random() * 10;

                if (number > 5) {
                   ( resolve("Resolved promise " + number));

                }
                else
              ( reject("Promise Rejected " + number));

        })};

            return obj;

        }


    var data = dataService();
    console.log(data);

   data.getData()
        .then(function(val) {
            console.log("It has been a success"),
            console.log(val)
         } )
        .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("It has been failed"),
                console.log(err)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `promise.resolve` and `promise.reject`. Just use `resolve` and `reject`.

Also, you need to actually return the promise from your `getData` function.

Try educating yourself with a tutorial, e.g. this one: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: still getting errors -->  Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. And  --> Uncaught (in promise) Promise Rejected 2.0840987564690128

Answer (score 0):

You are returning with an object instead of a promise object

```
obj.getData = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    // omitted
    return obj; // <---- culprit.
}
```

just return with `promise` instead

```
obj.getData = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    // omitted
    return promise; // <---- changed
}
```

so that when doing `data.getData()`, you will receive a Promise object. This object has `.then` and `.catch` functions.